# Is there a grep equivalent in OneNote?

Tags: windows, search, microsoft-onenote

grep prints lines on the terminal matching a given pattern. In OneNote, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>
 is how you do global search in OneNote. However, when you enter text in the search box, it shows you the list of notes that contain the search pattern without showing the lines within those notes that have the given pattern.

Is there a way to make OneNote search print lines like grep?

I am trying to do something very simple. My notes are littered with an `urgent_task` tag. For example:

```
bla bla bla 
bla bla bla 
urgent_task do xyz
bla bla bla 
bla bla bla
```

When I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and enter `urgent_task` I want OneNote to show me all the lines containing the word urgent_task, this way, I can glance through all of my urgent_tasks in one go, without maintaining a separate list.

Comment: don't you mean `CTRL & F`? with that you can move from one `urgent_task` to the next

Comment: @SimonS No, `Ctrl + F` searches within a note. `Ctrl+E` searches globally, i.e. all notes in all notebooks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to perform a search of all notebooks for a specific tag and create a Summary search report.  Do so as follows:

1. On the *Home* tab of OneNote's ribbon choose **Find Tags**
   [image]
2. In the Tag Summary dialog, specify your search settings. To search all notebooks, choose *All Notebooks* in the **Search:** drop down
   [image]
3. Click **Create Summary Page** to summarize the search results.
4. The full text of each tagged note will appear on a new OneNote "Summarized Search Results" page
5. To jump to the source page of a particular note, click the OneNote icon to the left of the search result
   [image]

---

Now, supposing you have a suggestion for improving this search functionality, 
Microsoft does accept [product suggestions for OneNote](https://onenote.uservoice.com/).  You can post your own suggestion, or vote for another such suggestion such as [this one](https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/327186-onenote-for-windows-windows-phone/suggestions/6900122-google-like-search).  I've done this for various Microsoft products and observed highly-voted suggestions being incorporated into product updates.